# get currunt item from viewpager android

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I using view pager for swipe view for android app. I build view pager Dynamically. Like add and remove item. Now i want to know how to get exactly position of view pager items.For example, I have 3 items, i want to get 3rd number position when i am in 2nd or 1st item. i used  `viewPager.getCurrentItem()` but it return where i am. 
Please suggest me how to give personal ids of every `viewpager` items and used it in when item is background or on screen.Thanks please help me about this, i left 2 weeks already for this. Thanks in advance

```
public TabsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return new MyWebBrowser();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
       return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return COUNT_TAB;
    }

}
```

Now this code Under my fragment class, from `WebView chrom class` i want to set up title as website title.

```
@Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            TAB_TITLE=title;

            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,title,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);

        }
```

Comment: you mean to say you want to access pages which are currently invisible from visible one??

Comment: yes, iwant to that page. Thanks for replay

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this Adapter:

```
 class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
        private final SparseArray<WeakReference<YourFragment>> mPageReferences;
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mPageReferences = new SparseArray<WeakReference<YourFragment>>();

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {

            WeakReference<YourFragment> fragment = 
                    new WeakReference<YourFragment>(YourFragment.newInstance());
            mPageReferences.put(i, fragment);
            return fragment.get();
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
            mPageReferences.remove(position);  
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return number of fragment;
        } 

        public YourFragment getFragment(int key) {      
            return mPageReferences.get(key).get();              

        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            WeakReference<YourFragment> fragment = new WeakReference<YourFragment>((YourFragment) super.instantiateItem(container,
                    position));
            mPageReferences.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment.get();
        }
    }
```

you can easily get the reference of any pages from `mPageReferences` BUT be careful because it may be null because it is possible that it has not created when you call it. you can use `(getFragment(int key)` to get the item at the position of `key`)

Answer (score 0):

you can know the current position from the `PagerAdapter`.
 by calling `pageAdapter.getItemPosition(itemNumber)`

[link to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getItemPosition%28java.lang.Object%29)